# why sometimes JVM get stuck few seconds and resume again in java?

Tags: java, linux

We have a java application running in production server.We noticed, nothing printed in log sometime and not processed any request for few seconds and resume again.We dont have any idea that which side we have to look to solve this problem.We sure that no thread got stuck application wise.it looked like entire process got freezed. i cannot doubt about linux server too. because, other component working fine.

I found similar problem discussed here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=231276

They were talking about Redhat os kernal.But, we are using centOs 7 .So I dont know how to relate to it.

Please give some advice that how to figure it out!!!

Comment: maybe your application is consuming so much of RAM, so thats why OS might suspend JVM for few seconds to priortize other tasks

Comment: you should monitor your RAM

Comment: Maybe it's because of the garbage collector? Run your application and monitor with for example Java VisualVM.

Comment: @MichaelDz no bro, those logs are also not printed in that time

Comment: Are you sure that you're logging gc activity (`-verbose:gc`) ?

Comment: @MichaelDz yes bro -verbose:gc -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:NewRatio

Comment: @Mustahsan bro how to find if it happened like you say "maybe your application is consuming so much of RAM, so thats why OS might suspend JVM for few seconds to priortize other tasks"

Comment: you need to monitor your application using jconsole/visual vm.

Comment: I can say so much: Imo bugreport is not directly relevant. But if you look at the steps the reporter of the bug took to find out what is going on. Those steps may help you narrowing down the problem(sorry: best advice I can give -  the information at hand is meager for a spot an analysis)

Comment: @jww if i know exact error, i should have given here.problem is everything freezed like three seconds and resume.(Dont be rude by down voting.this is not  a place showing who is the boss).

Answer (score -1):

Try taking thread dump for getting threads state information, could be a deadlock in case of database operations. You can take thread dump using jstack.